# How Many Hours of logs/console logs can be obtained from a iOS device?

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, itunes

I m not a iOS developer, but my team need helps in this, there is a issue in our iOS device app, we want to read logs from itunes, but i cant see consistency of timing of logs, few devices gave logs for past four hours and few only one hour. Can anyone please let me know that how many hours of logs (that we fetch from console). And if there is any way to increase it?

Answer (score 1):

Re: "how many hours of logs (that we fetch from console)": It varies depending on the verbosity of the device.

For example, on my iPhone 6s, the scrollback is about 40 minutes:

`Oct 11 21:44:07 cbownss-N71 Reminders[2087] <Notice>: Copying surface data to a new surface with required rowbytes alignment (16).
…
Oct 11 22:20:44 cbownss-N71 syslog_relay[2417] <Notice>: syslog_relay found the ASL prompt. Starting...`

Certain apps log a *lot* to the console, however (Rdio, I'm looking at you), so that'll decrease the buffer's time window to ten of minutes or less.

Re: "[is] there is any way to increase it?" Very likely not. The default size of the in-memory syslog is likely settable only by Apple internal defaults, or is a statically compiled limit.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a solution for this question, but as a alternative, we have kept all the logs in different file and added mailing service in our application, so now you don't even have to go to itunes, you can just click on 'Send Logs' button and send it to particular email id.

Hope this may help few people.